# How to use roImageCanvas in scene graph component

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am using **Scene Graph Component** to develop a application with **MarkupList** and **MarkupGrid**. I want a custom dialog box open when user exit from application. I am using **roImageCanvas** to create custom dialog box but don't know how to implement this. Main.brs file code is...

```
sub main()
screen = CreateObject("roSGScreen")
m.port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
screen.setMessagePor`enter code here`t(m.port)
scene = screen.CreateScene("HomeScene")
screen.show()

while(true)
msg = wait(1000, m.port)
msgType = type(msg)
if msgType = "roSGScreenEvent"

if msg.isScreenClosed() then showImageCanvas()
end if
end while
end sub
```

and roImageCanvas code is...

```
Sub showImageCanvas()
print "sdfsdf"
canvasItems = [
{
url:"http://192.168.1.23/boardwalk.jpg"
TargetRect:{x:100,y:100,w:400,h:300}
},
{
url:"http://192.168.1.23/walking.jpg"
TargetRect:{x:500,y:400,w:400,h:300}
},
{
Text:"Hello ImageCanvas"
TextAttrs:{Color:"#FFCCCCCC", Font:"Medium",
HAlign:"HCenter", VAlign:"VCenter",
Direction:"LeftToRight"}
TargetRect:{x:390,y:357,w:500,h:60}
}
]

canvas = CreateObject("roImageCanvas")
port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
canvas.SetMessagePort(port)
'Set opaque background
canvas.SetLayer(0, {Color:"#FF000000", CompositionMode:"Source"})
canvas.SetRequireAllImagesToDraw(true)
canvas.SetLayer(1, canvasItems)
canvas.Show()
while(true)
msg = wait(0,port)
if type(msg) = "roImageCanvasEvent" then
if (msg.isRemoteKeyPressed()) then
i = msg.GetIndex()
print "Key Pressed - " ; msg.GetIndex()
if (i = 2) then
' Up - Close the screen.
canvas.close()
end if
else if (msg.isScreenClosed()) then
print "Closed"
return
end if
end if
end while
End Sub
```

Generally i want when user exit from app showImageCanvas() should be called. I have also tried to put showImageCanvas() code in Scene file but it's always giving error so please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Scene Graph Component, you should use only one screen - **roSGScreen**, and one **Scene**. To show dialogues you should also use **Scene Graph** toolset. There is [Dialog](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Dialog) component for this purpose. To show confirmation dialog before channel close, you may add **onKeyEvent** observer to your **HomeScene** and show dialog like this:

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
    handled = false

    if press
        if key = "back"
            showExitConfirmationDialog()
            handled = true
        end if
    end if

    return handled
end function


sub showExitConfirmationDialog()
    dialog = createObject("roSGNode", "Dialog")
    dialog.message = "Are you sure you want to exit?"
    dialog.buttons = ["Cancel", "Exit"]
    dialog.observeField("buttonSelected", "onDialogButtonSelected")
    m.top.dialog = dialog
end sub


sub onDialogButtonSelected()
    if m.top.dialog.buttonSelected = 1
        m.top.close = true
    else
        m.top.dialog.close = true
    end if
end sub
```

Note that it is not possible to intercept **Home** button event, **Home** button will close the channel anyway.

To close the app, scene's "close" field is used, here is how you can add it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<component name="HomeScene" extends="Scene" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://rokudev.roku.com/rokudev/schema/RokuSceneGraph.xsd">

<script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/HomeScene.brs"/>

<interface>
    <field id="close" type="bool"/>
</interface>

</component>
```

also observe it in your main function:

```
sub main(params as Object)
    screen = createObject("roSGScreen")
    scene = screen.createScene("HomeScene")
    port = createObject("roMessagePort")
    screen.setMessagePort(port)
    screen.show()

    scene.observeField("close", port)

    while true
        msg = wait(0, port)

        if type(msg) = "roSGNodeEvent"
            if msg.getField() = "close" and msg.getData()
                return
            end if
        end if
    end while
end sub
```

Comment: Eugene Smoliy#
Thanks for reply. Can you please suggest how to customize the button of dialog box?

Comment: [Dialog](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Dialog) has "buttonGroup" field, which you can use instead of "buttons" if you need more customization. You have to set there [ButtonGroup](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/ButtonGroup) node instead of string array.

Comment: Eugene Smoliy@ Does roku supports pause/resume functionality during video buffering? Im using ".m3u8" file format.